# Creating options menu using Moxy library (Android)

Tags: android, android-moxy

I'm building an Android app using Moxy MVP library.

When I try to build the project, I get compilation error:

```
"Activity contains non-void method "onCreateOptionsMenu" that return type is boolean"
```

That is simple onCreateOptionsMenu methdod to inflate the menu.
Is there a way to use activity class containing this lifecycle method with Moxy Presenter?

Or what is the correct way to work with such lifecycle methods and Moxy?

Comment: Could you explain your question? It's not clear

Comment: Is it possible to use standard options menu in an activity which extends MvpAppCompatActivity? Thanks.

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible =) But I can't help till you explain your problem: what you have and what you want? In many cases you shouldn't put `onCreateOptionsMenu` to your view interface. And shouldn't call this method from presenter.